# Vue3: How to ignore text highlight events in @click?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a div which listens for click events like this:

```
  <div v-bind="$attrs"
       class="flex flex-col"
       @click="showEditModal = true">
  </div>
```

However, it also triggers when I highlight text after releasing the left mouse button. How do I ignore this type of clicks, and only trigger on simple click events?

Comment: Do you mean preventing copying the text?

Comment: I'm fine with copying text. I don't want @click to fire when the user is copying text.

Comment: check the answer i found a solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) if the selection is a `Range` like this one

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    clickme(e){
      if (document.getSelection().type === 'Range')           e.stopPropagation();
      else 
       console.log('welcome')
    }
  
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p @click="clickme">Welcome there</p>
</div>
```